# datefield xtype selection from yy to yyyy

Tags: aem

I am using widget textfield, when i select the date, it populate in format mm/dd/yy but i want mm/dd/yyyy. Does anyone has any idea about any configuration at dialog level that can make it possible. Here is my dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="printcoverage">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <articleDate
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        fieldLabel="Publication Date"
                        name="./publicationdate"
                        xtype="datefield"/>
                </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the **format** configuration to it. Try this

```
<articleDate
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  fieldLabel="Publication Date"
  name="./publicationdate"
  format="m/d/Y"
  xtype="datefield"/>
```

in the format config y = yy and Y = yyyyy . The complete list of config options can be found here -> http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1.1.1/#!/api/Date

Comment: Hi Thanks, It worked, But when i repoen the dialog date doesn't populate. Any Idea? I can see publicationdate set as string in JCR